# How to expose every pod individually?

Tags: kubernetes

need an advice. There’s a need to expose every pod individually to be externally reachable by some fqdn:port. It’s needed because pod is running stateful workload (media session).
It should be possible to run more than one pod on the node.

What is the scalable way to make every pod reachable and addressable?
What if it’s not necessarily HTTPS traffic that needs to be addressed to specific pod, but just TCP?

Comment: NodePort service is the first thought but you mention a reason you can't do that. Can each pod have its own k8s service?

Comment: @jordanm,
NodePort won't work because it can be only one pod per node then - it's NATting just one port.
Service per pod - I don't know what type of service? If it's LoadBalancer - it won't be scalable in Azure - it will use thousands of public LoadBalancers

Comment: I am unfortunately not familiar with Azure but in AWS there is a setting to allow one load balancer to handle multiple load balancer k8s services. Perhaps azure has a similar feature.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that for your intended state, grouping is not much help either.

Answer (score 1):

here is my idea

1. create a headless service, then you can access `pod-0.my-svc.my-ns.svc` from other pod.
2. create a proxy(nginx), config rewrite rule to rewrite `http://my-domain.com/pod-0` to `http://pod-0.my-svc.my-ns.svc/`
3. expose proxy(nginx) to `http://my-domain.com/`

---

I make a example for http, access `http://localhost:30000/nginx-sts-2/`
will response by pod `nginx-sts-2`. TCP should be similar but need to route by sub domain instead of path.

Here is that statfulset only response their pod name

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-sts
spec:
  replicas: 3
  serviceName: nginx-sts-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-sts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-sts
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-sts
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-sts-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-sts-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-sts-configmap
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-sts-configmap
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            return 200 "$hostname\n";
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-sts-service
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx-sts
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

here is the proxy that route `http://localhost:30000/nginx-sts-0` to pod `nginx-sts-0`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx-proxy
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nginx-proxy-config
          mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-proxy-config
        configMap:
          name: nginx-proxy-configmap
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy-configmap
data:
  nginx.conf: |
    server {
        resolver kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local valid=5s;
        listen 80;
        location ~ ^/nginx-sts-(\d+)/(.*)$ {
            set $backend http://nginx-sts-$1.nginx-sts-service.default.svc.cluster.local:80/$2;
            proxy_pass $backend;
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-proxy-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-proxy
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
```

Comment: Thanks, it might work!
What if we want to achieve the same without proxying, but with NAT, purely on TCP level,  so that first we need to traverse some externally visible IP to node IP and then translate node IP into pod IP?

Comment: even with NAT, you still need proxying.  
but ip assigned to pod would change, you can't use NAT.
and nginx can handle TCP level proxying.